# Android Apps on Chrome OS; What is going on?

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromebook

I've just discovered that my Chromebook is capable of downloading, installing and executing Android applications. As a developer, I'm very interested in the technical details as to what is going on; sadly, information on this appears to be very sparse.

From what I've learned, the Android applications operate within a segment of the operating system called a *container*, which is a dedicated bare-essentials runtime for Android. I've found that the `rootfs` is installed in `/opt/google/containers/android`, which I'm incapable of accessing, and that's about it!

I'd really appreciate if anyone could recommend any kind of documents or tutorials pertaining to the exploration of this very exciting aspect of Chrome OS.

Comment: This looks like a pretty useful tactic. https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeos/comments/4shsaz/install_superuser_for_android_on_the_flip/